# CSS for <select> menu works ... sometimes

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-selectmenu

This is bizarre.  I have a select menu that I've styled to display a hierarchical list.

I have multiple Firefox profiles setup to simulate multiple sessions.  One is my "main" profile with numerous extensions and customizations.

However, this is what my styled menu looks like in my "main" profile **while using safe mode**:

(EDIT: *Firefox's* safe mode that disables the extensions and resets the configuration)

[image]

This is what it looks like in a **clean, de-cached** Firefox profile:

[image]

For comparison's sake, Chrome and IE make it half-way there:

[image]

I've already got `-moz-appearance: none` and `-webkit-appearance:none;` for both the `<select>` and `<option>` elements.  The left offset on the options is achieved using `padding-left`.

The most perplexing thing is how this works in one Firefox profile (in safe mode) but not a completely clean one.

How do I make this consistently like the first example across all browsers?

Edit: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y645dpuf/2/)

Comment: Could you provide a working demo in JSfiddle, CodePen, or snippet?

Comment: post your css and html, otherwise we have nothing to work with

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have 3 options:

1. Pure Html:

   Add in blank non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` before your options in the lower levels and do it that way : not exactly kind to your time, and a bit messy-looking, but would work.

2. Pure CSS:

   Add on an additional class depending on the level ( [doesn't seem to work - already tried it](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/6vx6cLLo/) )

3. Jquery/Javascript: Probably the quickest way! If you are willing to use [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js) [or you could do it in plain js, but I've done the fiddle using jquery..]:
   Add in a hierarchy indicator using additional classes, depending on the level of the hierarchy  [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/8t4nauj2/) or snippet

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.l2').each(
      function() {
        $(this).text('--' + $(this).text());
      }
    );

    $('.l3').each(
      function() {
        $(this).text('----' + $(this).text());
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```css
#hierarchy,
#hierarchy>option {
  text-align: justify;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px grey; /*optional!*/
  word-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="hierarchy" name="hierarchy">
  <option class="l1" selected>Level 1</option>
  <option class="l2">First L2 Indent</option>
  <option class="l3">First L3 Indent</option>
  <option class="l2">Second L2 Indent</option>
  <option class="l3">Second L3 Indent</option>
  <option class="l3">Third L3 Indent</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the fiddle works in FF "safe mode" but if your computer is actually in safe mode,  it won't display in any case because internet will be disabled.. [well.. unless it's with networking]

Comment: so confused.  The fiddle works in my "main" FF profile (safe or regular mode), but not in a clean one.

Comment: You may have js disabled. Check your JavaScript settings

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic your question would be clearer if you outlined each of the profile settings and their intended use. Then other users could recreate them. (html would've been helpful tho too, i think that's why you got 3 close votes..) Just saying... for future reference. You can still edit the q to outline the browser preferences for the profile. Any result from the javascript settings check??

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic Which fiddle didn't work for you? I never got the css one to work, but the jquery one [in answer] worked cross browser in testing. Consider restarting in safe mode [without add-ons] on another/separate machine to test if that's a viable option [works fine on mine] if you don't want it resetting your config. What is a "clean" profile??? In what instances would a user use it?? It seems to be different from just regular mode from what you said. Please clarify. Thanks..

Comment: my "main" profile is for general use.  Numerous extensions (Web Developer, NoScript, etc.).  My clean profiles are just that: clean, no extensions or customizations.  Sorry, I should have posted a fiddle from the start.  I've tried it on IceWeasel in Debian (works with the CSS fiddle), Firefox on virtual machine and on a different PC (works with the CSS fiddle).  The only place it doesn't work is in my clean profiles on my main PC.  Completely perplexed as to why.

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic there have been issues with indenting options [with css] documented for  a good while now, and it's not just FF. See https://fettblog.eu/style-select-elements/ and https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/css-form-elements-problem/  My advice - use jquery. It's easily implemented and it works

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic do you have a fiddle ready to post? did you look at the codepen in the fettblog  article? The indentation works but it didn't work for me in jsfiddle, couldn't get it working after numerous attempts.. (http://codepen.io/ddprrt/pen/leLab .. the css codepen) Maybe you'll have more luck. If you get it going in jsfiddle will you post the link. Thanks. Seriously, lot of time for not even a vote. But hope I helped..